# NTLM Proxy with WinHTTP and Squid

Tags: c++, proxy, ntlm, squid, winhttp

We have a SQuid Proxy setup on Windows Server with NTLM authentication helper (mswin_ntlm_auth).

WinHTTP authentication as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144(v=vs.85).aspx is not getting passed and server is returning 407 even after passing correct credentails.

Setting WINHTTP_OPTION_AUTOLOGON_POLICY as LOW is also not self authenticating.

SQuid logs suggests as:
mswin_ntlm_auth[3384]: sending 'NA Got authentication request instead of negotiate request' to squid